# Power issues Skilsaw Model 77

Tags: electrical

I have a Skilsaw SHD 77 we bought new in 2015. We used it to build a 6' work bench and a chicken coupe. After sitting in a storage box for 2 years, I pulled it out to use and internal Sparks were higher than I remembered. Upon pulling the trigger again nothing/.

This is what I do know,

Brushes are clean, new and properly emplaced.

Power to and from the switch is proper via Multimeter

Blade turns by hand freely (unplugged)

no dust, grease or debri internally

Oil levels are good.

IT'S Basically NEW

Comment: Did you pull out the brushes? If not how do you know their condition?

Comment: Sounds like a brushes problem.  When they are not seating properly they make lots of sparks.  It sometimes take some time for the brushes to wear in/ break in.

Comment: Paul thank you for the feedback. The issue was over oxidation on the commutator.

Answer (score 1):

A properly running brushed motor should have a chocolate brown appearance this is a oxide that forms from moisture and brush wear. I do extensive work on brush based motors there is always arcing but it should be uniform and not very large. If the saw was in a damp location the windings may be saturated causing the higher than normal arcing. Using an ohm meter on the power plug with the trigger pulled you should see a low value of resistance, rotate the blade a little at a time you should have a similar resistance value through a full 360 reveloition of the commuminator. If you don't have any dead spots and the saw was in a damp location you may be able to bake it out in a oven at approx 150 deg F. I have to do this to motors that have been sitting on the shelf in an unheated warehouse when they are an open drip frame style.
If you have a electrician friend ask to meg the motor, this is a high voltage ohm meter that checks for leakage in the windings to the frame while turning to the different field windings with the trigger pulled these values should be at least 10meg at 250 v higher is better.
Checking the continuity blade to blade on the plug with the trigger pulled is usually less than 10 ohms and on some motors less than 1 ohm. If no continuity verify there is nothing stuck under the brushes and they are making contact, I have never seen a brush base motor With more than a couple fried coils if no continuity through 360 degrees rotation of the com a brush contact wire may have burned off or the wire at the switch since you said there was voltage at the switch.

Comment: Ed, thank you for the input! The Commutator Bar  was coated with oxidation, and whatever else. burlap cleaned it right up. I appreciate the education on the proper operating values, I would have never thought of checking them.

Answer (score 0):

If not the brushes, the commutator (the part of the rotor where the brushes connect) may have some surface oxidation and that will cause excessive sparking. It may just wear off with use.
[image]

Comment: The com should be chocolate brown in color with properly seated brushes,  people have brought me motors that they sanded the com and this blew the com because of copper dust between com's if a com needs to be cleaned the best ways are with com ruge sticks , but a dollar bill, or heavy canvas strip can be used. Any bright copper showing on a brush is an indication that something got stuck in there or the brush is at end of life (hitting the wire embedded in the brush if it was properly seated to start with.

Comment: J., Thank you! The commutator bar was the issue. I utilized some burlap to clean the surface and followed up with a vigorous blow off with the compressor. she is working now!